# How can we execute linux commands from php programs?

Tags: php, bash

I want to see the output of the following code in the web browser:

code:

```
<?php

      $var = system('fdisk -l');

      echo "$var";
?>
```

When I open this from a web browser there is no output in the web browser. So how can I do this? Please help!

Thanks
Puspa

Comment: Do you get a warning regarding safe mode maybe?

Answer (score 3):

you can use passthru, like so:

```
$somevar = passthru('echo "Testing1"');
// $somevar now == "Testing1"
```

or

```
echo passthru('echo "Testing2"');
// outputs "Testing2"
```

Comment: Although, if php doesn't have privileges to execute the command, you'll have trouble. In the case that you think you might be running into these issues, redirect stdout & stderr to a log file, and check it after you try.

You can send these to a log by appending this to the end of any shell command: >>logfile.log 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

use exec('command', $output);

print_r($output);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure that you (=user under which php runs) are allowed to call the external program (OS access rights, safe_mode setting in php.ini). Then you have quite a few options in PHP to call programs via command line. The most common I use are:

---

[system](http://de.php.net/system)

This function returns false if the command failed or the *last* line of the returned output.

```
$lastLine = system('...');
```

[shell_exec](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [backtick operators](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

This function/operator return the whole output of the command as a string.

```
$output = shell_exec('...'); // or:
$output = `...`;
```

[exec](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

This function returns the *last* line of the output of the command. But you can give it a second argument that then contains *all* lines from the command output.

```
$lastLine = exec('...'); // or capturing all lines from output:
$lastLine = exec('...', $allLines);
```

---

Here is the overview of all functions for these usecases: http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php